# remove the smallest element from a linkedlist

Tags: java, linked-list

What is the algorithm to remove the smallest element from a linked list without using remove() from linkedlist class. This is what I have to find the smallest data. I am making a Linkedlist class so I dont want to use the methods that are already there to do this.

```
public void removeSmallest(){
    Node smallest=new Node(); 
    Node temp=head;
    Node prev=null;
    while(temp!=null){
        if(temp.next.data<temp.data && temp.next!=null){
            smallest.data=temp.next.data;
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
public Node removeSmallest() {
   Node smallest = head; 
   Node temp = head;
   Node prev = null;

   while(temp != null) {
      if(temp.next != null && temp.next.data < smallest.data){
        smallest = temp.next;
        prev = temp;
      }
     temp = temp.next;
   }

   if(smallest != head) { //First element is not min
      prev.next = smallest.next;
   } else {
       head = head.next; //If first element is smallest, update the head
   }
   
   return head;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not really post what the problem is, but it might look like that your code is:

1. Not traversing the list, since temp is never updated (`temp = temp.next` after the `if` block should help).
2. You are not using the value of `prev` at all. It seems that your linked list implementation does not yield the parent of the node, which is something you would need so that you update the `next` of the parent node to be the node after the smallest one.
3. After you actually traverse the list, you are not removing the element.

Comment: My question is how to remove the smallest element after finding it from the list

Comment: @user2888979: If you take a look at the comments I have provided and implement them in your code, then your method should work.

Comment: As this looks like homework, and that's a big part of the linked list challenge, you won't find people who'll answer that for you without you giving a thought process, or evidence of an attempt. My advice is to draw down a linked list, and the connections between it, and imagine what you would have to do to remove an item while keeping the list as a whole intact.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit rusty on Java syntax but extending your code, I would think it would look like the following.

```
public void removeSmallest() {
    Node smallest = head; 
    Node temp = head;
    Node prev = null;

    while(temp != null) {
        if(temp.next != null && temp.next.data < smallest.data){
            smallest = temp.next;
            prev = temp;
        }
        temp = temp.next;
    }

    prev.next = smallest.next;
}
```

Comment: In retrospect, this ignores that prev could still be null if the first element in the list were smallest.  This could be handled with an explicit check at the end or assigning prev to a new node object and letting it get deleted when it falls out of scope.